# How can I make this form handler clearer/better?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, next.js

To start I'd like say that I'm a beginner writing my first Next.js app though I feel this question is more React related. I'm building an app where an user can add/edit stored food, recipes etc. which means I use a lot of submit form handlers. In every handler I:

1. Check if inputs are correct (I also do that directly in form)
2. Manage the data
3. Fetch to backend(Firebase)
4. Dispatch an action to Redux

The problem is that I feel like these handlers are too complicated and too "ugly". Could someone help me with what could I do better here ? I am thinking about exporting some functionality to custom hook or create some dynamic function but I have no idea how to do that here since all these handlers between adding/editing/removing food are so different (they are managing data much differently).

Below example form handler for editing food (the most "ugly" one)

```
const submitEditFoodHandler = async (e) => {
try {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (
    editFoodName.current.value.trim().length < 1 ||
    editFoodType.current.value === "DEFAULT" ||
    +editFoodQuantity.current.value < 0 ||
    editFoodQuantity.current.value.trim().length < 1
  ) {
    alert(ALERT_FOOD_EMPTY);
    return;
  } else if (!editFoodWeight.current.value.match(WEIGHT_REGEX)) {
    alert(ALERT_WEIGHT_FORMAT);
    return;
  }
  const foodObj = {
    username: foundUser.username,
    id: props.row.id,
    foodId: foundUser.foodId,
    name: editFoodName.current.value,
    type: editFoodType.current.value,
    quantity: editFoodQuantity.current.value,
    weight: editFoodWeight.current.value,
    expDate: editFoodExpDate.current.value,
    key: props.row.key,
  };

  const foodCopy = [...foundUser.food];
  const foundUserFoodIndex = foodCopy.findIndex(
    (ele) => +ele.id === +props.row.id
  );

  foodCopy[foundUserFoodIndex] = {
    name: editFoodName.current.value,
    type: editFoodType.current.value,
    quantity: editFoodQuantity.current.value,
    weight: editFoodWeight.current.value,
    expDate: editFoodExpDate.current.value,
    id: props.row.id,
    key: props.row.key,
  };

  const payload = {
    username: foundUser.username,
    recipesId: foundUser.recipesId,
    foodId: foundUser.foodId,
    totalWeight:
      foundUser.totalWeight -
      getNumberFromStr(props.row.weight) +
      getNumberFromStr(editFoodWeight.current.value),
    totalQuantity:
      foundUser.totalQuantity -
      props.row.quantity +
      +editFoodQuantity.current.value,
    food: foodCopy,
    recipes: foundUser.recipes,
  };

  const docRef = doc(db, "users", foundUser.id);
  await setDoc(docRef, payload);
  dispatch(fridgeActions.editFood(foodObj));

  editFoodName.current.value = "";
  editFoodType.current.value = "";
  editFoodQuantity.current.value = "";
  editFoodWeight.current.value = "";
  editFoodExpDate.current.value = "";
  props.setShowEditFoodModal(false);
} catch (err) {
  alert(ALERT_OTHER);
  console.error(err);
}};
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more about architecture, in this case if you have a lot of fields things will get bigger eventually, based on what you said/showed there are a few things that I can see you could do to improve the quality of your code

- DRY, Search for places where you're doing things more than 1 time and try to abstract them
- If you want your app to scale I REALLY recommend you to find a form library based on your needs; take a look:

  - [formik](https://formik.org/)
  - [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/)
- Try splitting the responsibilities, you could take your complicated form and split it into other components, like one for handling Network related stuff, another only for the logic and one for rendering the form itself, errors feedback etc